# Why do I keep getting the $[injector:modulerr] uncaught error when all dependencies have been injected?

Tags: angularjs

Below is my index.html page which has two buttons which links to 2 different views which i intend to show using angular routing.

Below is my

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PR_APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="new_pr_app">
    <h2>Please select an option</h2><br>
    <div ng-controller="view_controller">
        <button id="view_details" ng-click="view()">View Details</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="update_controller">
        <button id="update_details" ng-click="update()">Update Details</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-view>

    </div>

</body>
```

Below is my main.js file which houses both above mentioned controller and logic for angular routing.

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('new_pr_app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config('$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/update",
        {
            templateUrl:"update.html",
            controller: "update_controller"
        })
        .when("/view", 
        {
            templateUrl: "view.html",
            controller: "view_controller"
        });
});

app.controller("view_controller",function($scope, $location, http_factory){
$scope.view = function(){
    $location.path("/view");
}
    $scope.result =[];
    http_factory.get_request().then(function(response){
        $scope.result = response.data;    
    });
});

app.controller("update_controller",function($scope, $location, http_factory){
$scope.update_details = function(){
    $location.path("/update");
}
    $scope.names = [];
    http_factory.get_request().then(function(response){
        $scope.names = response.data;
    });
});
```

I have another file called services.js which has a service factory to get details from a json file using an http get.

My only problem seems to be in the above main.js which gives the error below everytime `index.html` loads

> angular.js:88 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: What is http_factory?

Comment: Post the exact and complete error, after you've replaced angular.min.js by angular.js

Comment: @JBNizet the is the error from min.js as angular.js gives too long an error
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=new_pr_app&p1=Error…udflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)
    at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:4957
    at p (angular.js:410)
    at g (angular.js:4917)
    at gb (angular.js:4839)
    at c (angular.js:1949)
    at Uc (angular.js:1970)
    at xe (angular.js:1855)
    at angular.js:33826
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3468)

Comment: @Vivz http_factory is my service_factory that makes an http get request and returns details from a json file.

Comment: Post the exact and complete error, **in your question**, after you've **replaced angular.min.js by angular.js**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is wrong. You pass in a string as the first (and second argument), while the `.config(..)` function, expects a function to be passed in (or an array).

In your code, you simply forgot to wrap the arguments in an array. Here's how it should look:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/update",
        {
            templateUrl:"update.html",
            controller: "update_controller"
        })
        .when("/view", 
        {
            templateUrl: "view.html",
            controller: "view_controller"
        });
    }]);
```

Note the `[` and `]` wrapping the content

Answer (score 0):

You can check with below code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.js"></script>
<body ng-app="new_pr_app">



  <h2>Please select an option</h2><br>
    <div ng-controller="view_controller">
        <button id="view_details" ng-click="view()">View Details</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="update_controller">
        <button id="update_details" ng-click="update_details()">Update Details</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-view>

    </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('new_pr_app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/update",
        {
            template:"update template"
           // controller: "update_controller"
        })
        .when("/view", 
        {
            template: "view template"
           // controller: "view_controller"
        });
}]);

app.controller("view_controller",function($scope, $location){
$scope.view = function(){
    $location.path("/view");
}
});

app.controller("update_controller",function($scope, $location){
$scope.update_details = function(){
    $location.path("/update");
}
    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```